# Hibernate custom types together with JPA2 criteria

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0, criteria

as for legacy reasons we are storing dates as NUMBER in our oracle db (e.g. 1101980 is October 1st 1980).

We're using jboss AS 7.1.2 and along with it hibernate as persistence provider.
To be able to use java.util.Date in my entities I created a hibernate custom type to translate between java.util.Date and the NUMBER from the database. The entity's property is annotated with hibernate's `@Type` accordingly.

So far this has worked quite good. However now we're starting to use JPA 2's criteria api and for these queries the custom types do not get applied.

E.g. I'm setting the date of birth to a java.util.date:

```
Predicate birthday = cb.equal( person.get( Person_.dateOfBirth ), date );
```

but when I execute the query I get

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got TIMESTAMP

this indicates that the custom type does not get applied. Is there a way to get around this?  Maybe by using any hibernate's specific criteria apis? I really don't want to have `Long` as date in my entities

Comment: I just tried doing the same thing with JPQL and it works... I can set a java.util.date on the entity and will be able to execute query.getResultList()
anyway I'd rather use criteria api for type-safety and to avoid the hassle of dynamically concatenating the querystring

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem, just that we transform List<String> via UserType.. We end up having a list as a single String in a DB..

When I use the criteria API to query with respect to the list content, my list object that I add as cb.equal( root.get("ips"), listOfIps); is actually translated to number of parameters, equal to the number of entries in the list.. I end up with query like ..where e.ips = {:p1, :p2, :p3} which is not valid at all..

Is it possible that the transformation with the user type does not happen.. Or the problem can be that @Type is Hibernate related?